# Pronunciation of "chase"

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonology

I've always pronounced “chase” with a z sound instead of s.
This will go with the rule that s is pronounced z if it is between 2 vowels.
I see anyway that the correct pronunciation is with s.

[Chase - Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/chase)

Is there a reason or rule for that?

Comment: Good question - But! : There is no rule that 's' is pronouced as /z/ between vowel sounds in English!

Comment: We also have the word *chaise*, and the "s" is pronounced as /z/ and the "ch" as /sh/. There are no rules  just tendencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason?

Yes, there is.

First of all, there are no rules that tell you how to pronounce an English word, based on its spelling.

Let me repeat that:

> There are no rules that tell you how to pronounce an English word, based on its spelling.

That may be a bit shocking, but it's true.

But, but, there *must* be rules, how else do people know how to pronounce words?

Well, it's a common mistake to think that we pronounce words as they are written; it's the other way around: **we write words as they are pronounced**.

Now, in the case of English, spelling was decided on quite a long time ago for most words. The difficult part is that we spell English *today* in a way that it was *pronounced* a long time ago.

That's the short version. There have been some spelling reforms (for instance, Noah Webster did his best to make American English spelling more "logical"), but the main idea is just that: we write English the way it was pronounced a long time ago.

This means there are many words that are not pronounced in the way you would expect when looking at their spelling. One of the best illustrations of that is the poem [**The Chaos**](http://clamen.net/stewart/cs.cmu.edu/misc/humour/TheChaos.html). It was written by Dr. Gerard Nolst Trenité, a Dutchman who probably felt the same frustration as many learners of English when trying to figure out the relationship between spelling and pronunciation in English.

There are different things that influence spelling, this answer is hardly complete. For a more detailed post on that, please see this [excellent answer by Ben Kovitz](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24515/you-cant-spell-slaughter-without-laughter/24644#24644).

Comment: Hmmm I'm very skeptical about tht rule. I don't even think it's a generalisation. Can you give some examples by any chance?

Comment: @Araucaria: it's why I wrote "rule" and why I mentioned again it is _not_ a rule... I spent my whole answer saying there _are no rules_, I certainly didn't want that last paragraph suggesting that there actually _is_ a rule. But it is indeed as bad a generalization as the OP's version, so to avoid confusion, I have removed the last paragraph altogether :)

Comment: +1 for explaining that it's "the other way around". I read your answer as a denial of the assumption that there must be a rule, not an affirmation. BTW, there's more to English spelling than attempting to represent pronunciation; that's a common misunderstanding (or mis-expectation). A short "long version" of factors is [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24644/6700), including the principle that morphemes often have distinct but consistent spellings. See also "The Spelling and Pronunciation of English" by Wayne O'Neil, if you can find it.

Comment: May be better to say there are "patterns" in English spelling than rules - and always exceptions.

Comment: @BenKovitz: I tried to keep it simple... your answer is amazingly detailed, I hope you don't mind if I reference it in my answer?

Answer (score 6):

**There is no hard and fast (reliable) rule**. Here are a few examples of /s/ and /z/ sounds when the "s" is sandwiched between vowels:

With /s/: case, base, chase, vase*, erase

With /z/: phase, phrase, laser, quasar

([Source](https://www.englishforums.com/English/TheSoundBeginningMiddle-Words/clxdc/post.htm), third response.)

- Note that "vase" is pronounced by many people with a /z/. See [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vase)

The same response has a nice list of /s/ vs /z/ sounds for you.

Comment: Except *vase* can be pronounced as either an -s- or -z-.

Comment: Fair point. In my accent, that's a /z/ (BrE).

Comment: vase is a confusing example, because the a has 2 options as well - in my accent, it's vahse.

Comment: *Erase* is /z/ in BrE as well. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/erase

Comment: In England, it's vase with an s, not a z.

Comment: @SteveIves not usually. The usual UK pronunciation of "vase" is /vɑːz/.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason or rule for that?

There are no fixed rules as others have said.

> I've always pronounced “chase” with a z sound instead of s. *This will go with the rule that s is pronounced z if it is between 2 vowels*. I see anyway that the correct pronunciation is with s.

This is not true for the most part. Whether or not the letter S in a particular word is pronounced /s/ or /z/ depends entirely on the evolution of the word. See for instance ['lose' vs 'loose'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272566/106592); 'lose' is a native English word and it underwent the voicing in Old English. 'Loose' on the other hand came from Old Norse and didn't undergo the voicing rule.

Most 'native' English words in which the letter S represents the /z/ sound went through the fricative voicing I explained in the answer I linked above. 'Chase' came from Old French in the thirteenth century by the time English had lost the voicing, so it retained its original [s] sound.