# Why are "LOse" and "LOOse" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, orthography, phonology, consonants

I know that both the words are pronounced and used differently. I also found another question on this site: "[Use of loose and lose [closed]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126773/use-of-loose-and-lose)", but that is about the usage of the word. My question is completely different to that one.

The ending *'se'* is pronounced 's' in loose and 'z' in lose: respectively, /luːs/ and /luːz/. What caused this change?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## ;

'Lose' came from Old English (OE) word *losian* while 'loose' was taken from Old Norse around the thirteenth century. There was a process in OE through which *s, f* and *th* became voiced respectively to [z], [v] and [ð] when they occurred between voiced sounds i.e. between two vowels or a vowel and anther voiced sound. There was no phonemic contrast of voice among the OE fricatives.

The ⟨s⟩<sup>**1**</sup> in the OE form of 'lose' was intervocalic (between vowels), so it became [z] which survived into Modern English (ModE).

'Loose' came into English in the thirteenth century by the time the voicing was no longer productive, so it retained the original [s] sound.

There are lots of pairs that exhibit the same sound change such as *wolf/wolves, bath/bathe, house (n)/house (v), breath/breathe, life/lives, loaf/loaves, close (adj)/close (v), knife/knives, cloth/clothes* etc. All these are the remnants of OE property called [**intervocalic fricative voicing**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269044/106592)

#### Fricative voicing

Old English had a phonetic property called **fricative voicing**, whereby non-velar fricatives—s, þ ~ ð<sup>**2**</sup>, f—became voiced when they were flanked by vowels, or a vowel and another voiced consonant. The fricatives *s, þ ~ ð, f* were voiceless elsewhere. /ʃ/ was always voiced.

There were no distinctive voiced fricatives in Old English. The realisations [f - v], [θ - ð] and [s - z]<sup>**3**</sup> were allophonic. It was the only way to get [z], [v] and [ð] because Old English didn't have phonemic [z], [v] and [ð]. In a nutshell:

- [f] and [v] were the allophones of the phoneme /f/
- [s] and [z] were the allophones of the phoneme /s/
- [θ] and [ð] were the allophones of the phoneme /θ/

#### Examples

- *Wolf* was *wulf* and it would've been pronounced [wulf], *wolves* was *wulfas* and would've been pronounced [wul**v**ɑs].
- *House* (noun) was *hūs* and would've been pronounced [huːs], *house* (verb) was *hūsian* and would've been pronounced something like [huː**z**iɑn].
- *Bath* (noun) was *bæþ* and pronounced [bæθ], *bathe* was *baþian* and would have been pronounced [ˈbɑ.ði.ɑn].
- *Close* (verb) was *clȳsan* and would've been phonetically [ˈklyː.zɑn], *close* (adj) was *clȳs*, and would've been [klyːs].

Note that the fricatives were **phonemically** voiceless; the voicing was **allophonic**.

#### Lose vs loose

**Lose** came from Old English *losian*. The *s* was intervocalic, so it became [z] due to that property:

- *losian* → [ˈlo.zi.ɑn]

In Middle English, it became *losen* ([ˈloːzən]), then it lost the terminal nasal and became [ˈloːzə], then the terminal schwa was lost and the vowel [oː] was changed to [uː] by the Great Vowel Shift.

**Loose** entered English [in the 13th century](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=loose) and by that time, the voicing wasn't productive anymore. So it retained its original /s/.

---

1. I use **⟨angled brackets⟩** for orthography/spelling.
2. *þ* (*thorn*) and *ð* (*eth*) were used interchangeably by OE scribes to represent the *th* sounds. Do not confuse *ð* with IPA [ð].
3. **[Square brackets]** are for allophones/contextual variants.

Comment: I had no idea wolf/ wolves underwent the same process. I have always wondered about that.

Comment: @MackJad: In modern English, this dynamic is apparent in the way that these noun or adjective + verb pairings generally have voicing on the verb, and no voicing on the noun or adjective.  Compare also _breath_ and _breathe_, _swath_ and _swathe_, _life_ and _live_, _strife_ and _strive_, _cleft_ and _cleave_, _heft_ and _heave_, _weft_ and _weave_.

Comment: Oddly, while I can think of other examples of other words with "*-oose*" (*moose, goose, caboose*), I know of no other example of a word spelled with "*-ose*" that's pronounced that way.  They're all pronounced with a long 'o' instead either with an 's' sound (*dose, close (adj.), morose, comatose*) or a 'z' sound (*rose, chose, close (v.), dispose*).  One word that is pronounced like "*lose*" but spelled like "*loose*" is "*choose*".  English is just weird.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, the one unvoiced-noun + voiced-verb pair that I can think of that includes a rhyme with /-uːz/ is _use_ (noun) + _use_ (verb).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: "I know of no other example of a word spelled with _"-ose"_ that's pronounced [to rhyme with _lose_]." How about _whose_. :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Yeah, there's plenty of words that rhyme with *lose*, but most of them, like your example, are spelled with a 'u'.  Either "*-use*" (*use, peruse, confuse*), "*-ues*" (*dues, hues, blues*), or sometimes "*-ouse*" (*Toulouse* is the only one of those I can think of that gets used in English, and it might not really count since it's French and a proper noun - there's a bunch of French words like that.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Good point, so now we have 2.  It's still kind of the exception for that spelling though.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I read somewhere that the /uː/ in *lose* is by analogy with *loose*. It should've been */əʊ/ (vowel in 'no') but it isn't.

Answer (score 9):

"Loose" has probably always been pronounced with [s] - the Norse word that it was borrowed from is spelt with double "s".

"Lose" has been pronounced with [z] at least since Old English.  (Between vowels, OE "s" was pronounced [z].  I use square brackets here because the s/z distinction in OE wasn't phonemically significant - they were allophones.)

The words "loose" and "lose" are etymologically only very distantly related: they derive from different Germanic roots (but probably have a common origin in Proto-Indo-European).

You should not expect to see a close or consistent sound/spelling relationship in English.

Comment: [Jinx!!!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272566/106592)

Comment: Yes.  As in all questions of this sort, they're different words, and so are pronounced differently (depending on one's local accent, of course). Spelling came later, and is only approximately phonetic.

Answer (score 3):

They are different words spelled differently with different meanings.
Hence they are pronounced differently.

Comment: Unfortunately your reasoning is not correct. In fact English has a lot of homophones—words with different meanings (and possibly spellings), that are pronounced exactly the same.

Comment: I'll give this a +1 because while the linguistic stuff is interesting, is not really a surprise that two words with different spellings and meanings are not pronounced the same

Comment: @bodo And on top of that, homographs that are *not* pronounced the same ("close", "house", etc. as in the current top answer here)!

Comment: Some ***very*** common ones are: *["you're"/"your"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-You%27re-and-Your)*, *["there"/"their"/"they're"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-There,-Their-and-They%27re)*, *["than"/"then"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Than-and-Then)*, *"affect"/"effect"*, *["were"/"where"/"we're"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Where,-Were-and-We're)*, *["whose"/"who's"](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Commonly-Misused-Words#.22Who.27s.22_and_.22Whose.22_sub)*, *"alot"/"allot"/"a lot"*, and *"definitely"/"definately"* (some are regional. And other reasons.)