# Why isn't there a way to say "catched up"? We can only say "caught up"

Tags: orthography, conjugations, irregular-forms

I am realizing sometimes when talking, I always say:

> Oh that guy catched up with me!

But then I realized there is a way to say:

> Oh that guy caught up with me!

I may think the grammar of "caught up" is more proper, but I seem to feel that it is a bit strange to say "caught up", whereas "catched up" sounds a bit better...

But I would like to know which is proper grammar. I often use that term and I wonder which is preferred and more efficient to use.

Comment: Check a [conjugation guide](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-catch.html) for the verb "to catch".  You'll find that "catched" is not present, while "caught" is.

Comment: English, being a very eclectic hodgepodge, has a lot of irregular verbs like that. "I call now, and called then"; but "I fall now, and fell then". It even goes further, to what's called "suppletion", where different tenses of the same verb are unrelated words with completely separate etymologycal origins, which is why the past tense of "go" is "went", not "goed". (And it's not just verbs: "father"/"paternal" have a suppletive relationship.) Here is an interesting blog post on the subject: https://blog.oup.com/2013/01/why-is-the-past-tense-of-go-went-suppletion/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Caught up" is correct.

I'm not sure "catched" is ever correct.
[Merriam-Webster lists it as "chiefly dialectal".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catched)

Answer (score 14):

*Caught* is the 'standard' past and past participle of *catch* now, but it wasn't always the case. The correct past and past participle of *catch* was ***[catched](https://www.etymonline.com/word/caught)***. The current past and past participle [*caught*, is by analogy with *teach/taught*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592).

[Analogical change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogical_change) is a type of language change in which some forms are deliberately changed merely to make them look more like other forms (Trask).

Larry Trask—a great linguist—says in his book *Trask's Historical Linguistics* that the earlier, and 'fully natural' *catch/catched* has now been ousted by the decidedly less natural catch/caught.

He further says that the speakers who still say *catched* are regarded by some as rustic or ignorant. He also says that he himself uses *catched* occasionally.

Comment: I've expounded on analogy in [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592)

Comment: Yeah but *why* : "A rare instance of an English strong verb with a French origin. This might have been by influence of Middle English *lacchen* (see latch (v.)), which also then meant "to catch" and was more or less a synonym of *catch* (as their noun forms remain), and which then had past tense forms *lahte, lauhte, laught*." ... because *catch* was influenced by the French *lacchen*; past tense: *laught*.

Comment: @Mazura: Quite possibly. But I checked some reputable and reliable sources that say that *caught* is due to analogy.  (Link fixed... thanks for pointing out. I was typing on phone that's why...)

Comment: According to Google N-grams (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catched%2F%28catched%2Bcaught%29&year_start=1600), "catched" has at no point in the last 400 years been even a quarter of usages. If it was ever "correct", it was long ago indeed.

Comment: @Xerxes: But I've certainly heard 'catched' used by native English speakers. Some dialects of English still use 'catched' as a past and past participle of 'catch'.

Comment: In the example sentence given by the OP, "catched" is being used as the past tense, not the past participle.

Comment: @Acccumulation And? Aren't the past and past participle of 'catch' identical?

Comment: Your answer talks about the past participle. The past tense and part participle happen to be the same in this case, but that doesn't mean that statements about one answer a question about the other.

Comment: @Acccumulation: I added that to my answer.