# What can be a possible reason for phonological changes in English?

Tags: dictionaries, phonology, history

I was reading [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English) Wikipedia article. It is describing the major phonological changes in English over a period of time but no reason is given for any changes.

Kindly correct me if I am wrong, the changes occurred because majority of people started to use some other phonetics and due to this the phonological changes had occurred.

Kindly shed some light on other possible reasons for phonological changes. Also, what are the factors on which dictionaries adopt new words and new phonetics.

Comment: I've explained it briefly in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/267604/106592)

Comment: @Void The reason I have mentioned can that be one of the possibilities? And what about modern day dictionaries, why they change over time? Sir kindly enlighten me.

Comment: There's a whole lot of history behind it. You may be right... but there are so many reasons. I've explained the major ones in the answer I linked. Present day English dictionaries change because language isn't stagnant. For example, the past and past participle of 'catch' used to be 'catched', but [it's caught now](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269941/106592)